# html dom Load() current page

Tags: php, dom

I have a php file with a function which checks for an `elementid`. I can check HTML strings, but I am at a loss on how to check the current page (preferably without explicitly defining it).

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->validateOnParse = true;

$doc->loadHTML($htmlstring); // ok
$doc->Load(); // ?

$doc->getElementById('div-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is no **"current page"**. PHP outputs text, that is interpreted by the receiving browser and rendered as a web page.

You can however write all you output into a variable or use the [output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions to capture the output generated by echo and other functions.